# GetElementbyID fails to fire

Tags: javascript

From my reading here I would expect this code to work, but it doesn't. I have tried two ways to add click events to a button called "lonext". Neither work. I'm not sure why this might be?

```
window.onload = function() {

var goSC = function() { //go to the sucess criteria section
    document.getElementsByClassName("guidance1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("guidance2").style.display = "";
    alert("button clicked");

//first try
document.getElementById("lonext").addEventListener("click", function() {
    goSC();     
    }, false);

//second try
document.getElementById("lonext").onclick = goSC;

}
```

Comment: You should show your HTML and how you implemented the JavaScript in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) because you could have many elements in your DOM with the same class, not a single element.

So:

```
var goSC = function() {
    var guidance1 = document.getElementsByClassName("guidance1");
    for (var i = 0; i < guidance1.length; i++) {
         guidance[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    var guidance2 = document.getElementsByClassName("guidance2");
    for (var i = 0; i < guidance2.length; i++) {
         guidance[i].style.display = "";
    }

    alert("button clicked");
});

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("lonext").onclick = goSC;
};
```

which if you used [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) could be simplified to:

```
$(function() {
    $('#lonext').click(function() {
        $('.guidance1').hide();
        $('.guidance2').show();
    });
});
```

I would also strongly recommend you using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome Developer toolbar to inspect your javascript code and see potential errors with it. The `Console` tab will contain valuable information about possible errors in your javascript code.

Comment: Nit: `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array, but an array-like `HTMLCollection` object. This distinction matters, because otherwise you'd expect that the result would support array methods such as [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), etc., which isn't true.

Comment: Actually it's a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) not an array; that means you won't be able to use array iterators like `forEach`.